# File Writing and Redirect output not working when using URLLIB2 in python

Tags: python, bash, httprequest, urllib2

I am using python urllib2 module to make calls to a web page and get the result. 
The script runs fine when I don't redirect the output of the script to another file like:

```py
python make_req.py #or
python make_req.py &
```

However when I am trying to redirect the output of the command to another file like:

```py
python make_req.py > file_req.out &
```

In this case my output file is always empty even after killing the process however the process continues to run.

I also tried using a file pointer inside the file for writing the output but that also doesn't work when running the code.

I have tried commenting out the line with `data = urllib2.urlopen(full_url)` in it and that has solved the problem. But when I uncomment the line the problem reappears. I believe it is because of something with urllib2 module. Without the file redirect or the write file pointer, the data line works perfect.

Please suggest some alternative or a solution.

My code is pretty simple as follows:

```py
# Make request

import urllib2
import urllib

def makeReq(name, fp1):
  data = {}
  data['name'] = name
  url_values = urllib.urlencode(data)
  #print url_values  # The order may differ. 

  url = 'SOME_URL'
  full_url = url + '?' + url_values
  print >> fp1, full_url
  data = urllib2.urlopen(full_url)

with open("names.tsv") as fp , open("file_req.out", "wb+") as fp1:
  uniq_names = fp.read().splitlines()
  for name in uniq_names:
    name = name.split('\t')
    if int(name[1]) > 10: 
      makeReq(name[0], fp1)
      print >> fp1, "Finished processing %s with count %s" % (name[0], name[1])
  print >> fp1, "Finished processing all names."
```

Comment: Could you explain what is `fp1` in your code, and what output goes to `stdout` ?

Comment: `fp1` is the file I am trying to write to. Earlier I was writing to stdout then I tried using file pointer and both methods don't work.

Comment: You should try to add debugging prints to `sys.stderr` to see verify if your program really blocks on the line `data = urllib2.urlopen(full_url)` or if other things happen.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you open the file file_req.out and write results in it inside your program, but later you redirect stdout to the same file.  The later content will override the former data and the later one is obviously nothing, so you will see file_req.out is always empty.

Comment: No I don't the `fp1` was used only after the stdout printing didn't work.

Comment: If you do not open fp1 and print the data to stdout instead of fp1, you should get what you expect.